# Checking if a string is a palindrome - when I compile the program shuts down

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a C program which eats a string of a priori bounded length and returns 1 if it's a palindrome and 0 otherwise. We may assume the input consists of lower case letters.

This is a part of a first course in programming, so I have no experience.

Here's my attempt. As soon as I try to build/run it on CodeBlocks, the program shuts down. It's a shame because I thought I did pretty well.

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#define MaxLength 50

int palindrome(char *a,int size) /* checks if palindrome or not */
{
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size/2;i++) /* for every spot up to the middle */
        {
            if (*(a+i)!=*(a+size-i-1)) /* the palindrome symmetry condition */
            {
                c++;
            }
        }

    if (c==0)
    {
        return 1; /*is palindrome*/
    }
    else
        return 0; /*is not palindrome*/
}

int main()
{
char A[MaxLength]; /*array to contain the string*/
char *a=&A[0]; /*pointer to the array*/
int i=0; /*will count the length of the string*/
int temp;
    while ((temp=getchar())!='\n' && temp != EOF) /*loop to read input into the array*/
    {
        A[i]=temp;
        i++;
    }
if (palindrome(a,i)==1)
    printf("1");
else
    printf("0");
return 0;
}
```

**Remark.** I'm going to sleep now, so I will not be responsive for a few hours.

Comment: The code won't compile because you should replace the `=` in `#define MaxLength=50` with a blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is ok, though you have a number of small errors.  First,`#define MaxLength=50` should be `#define MaxLength 50` (the text to replace, space, then its replacement).

You should also provide a prototype for your `palindrome()` function before `main()`:

```
int palindrome(char *a,int size);
```

...or just move the whole `palindrome()` function above `main()`.  Either a prototype or the actual function definition should appear before any calls to the function happen.

Next issue is that you're looking for a null character at the end of the input string.  C strings are usually null terminated, but the lines coming from the console aren't (if there's a terminator it would be added by your program when it decides to end the string) -- you should probably check for a newline instead (and ideally, for errors as well).  So instead of

```
while ((temp=getchar())!='\0')
```

try

```
while ((temp=getchar())!='\n' && temp != EOF)
```

When you print your results in `main()`, you should have a newline at the end, eg. `printf("1\n");` instead of `printf("1");`, to ensure the output buffer gets flushed so you can see the output as well as to end that output line.

Then in your `palindrome()` function, your `for` loop sytax is wrong -- the three parts should be separated with semicolons, not commas.  So change:

```
for(int i=0,i<size/2,i++)
```

...to:

```
for(int i=0; i<size/2; i++)
```

You also have an extra closing brace for the loop body to remove.

After fixing all that, it seems to work...

Comment: Thank you. Apart from what you wrote about `printf`, I edited everything (and posted the edit), but still, CodeBlocks shuts down immediately.

Comment: I just tried to run a much more basic code. The program runs and immediately returns 000. Ignores the code completely. Do you any idea why this is? The code I ran is from the first example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm). It doesn't even wait for any input.

Comment: @Arrow Check the project options, under "Build targets", and make sure "Type" is a console application and that "Pause when execution ends" is enabled for the target you're using.

Comment: @Arrow Also, check the "Build log" and "Build messages" windows to see if they show any errors.

Answer (score 2):

This directive

```
#define MaxLength=50
```

is invalid. There should be

```
#define MaxLength 50
```

Change the loop in main the following way

```
int temp;
^^^
while ( i < MaxLength && ( temp = getchar () )!= EOF && temp != '\n' )
{
    A[i] = temp;
    i++;
}
```

Otherwise if to use the original loop you have to place the zero into the buffer directly using the alt key and the numeric keypad.

The function itself can be written simpler

```
int palindrome( const char *a, int size) /* checks if palindrome or not */
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < size / 2 && *( a + i ) == *( a + size - i - 1 ) ) ++i;         {

    return i == size / 2;
}
```

Comment: The program still shuts down as soon as I try to run.

Comment: @Arrow Before the end of the program insert statement scanf( " %c", &temp );

Comment: Codeblocks still shuts down as soon as I try to run.

Comment: @Arrow Well, try the following before the end of the prigram fegts( A, sizeof( A ), stdin ); scanf( " %c", &temp );

Comment: I haven't learned these commands, so I am not allowed to use them.

Comment: By the way, is my solution correct? At least conceptually?

Comment: @Arrow The problem is that the program runs and the window closes. You should check whether there is a mode to run the program with a pause before closing the window. As for the function then it is correct but contains redundant code.